# How can i add: jquery popper.js bootstrap to ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

When I'm adding this: `yarn add jquery popper.js bootstrap` to the terminal
i am getting this:

```
yarn add v1.22.17
warning package.json: No license field
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
warning No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > bootstrap@5.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "@popperjs/core@^2.10.2".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
warning No license field
success Saved 3 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ bootstrap@5.1.3
├─ jquery@3.6.0
└─ popper.js@1.16.1
info All dependencies
├─ bootstrap@5.1.3
├─ jquery@3.6.0
└─ popper.js@1.16.1
Done in 0.37s.
```

and nothing is added, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

> warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json

This suggests your project is using `npm` and not `yarn`.

- Try using `npm add ...` to add the packages.
- Alternatively, it's important to ensure the same package manager is used. If this is a new project, consider removing the `package-lock.json` and doing a fresh install with `yarn` - or vice versa.

> and nothing is added, what am I doing wrong here?

- My guess is this is added to the `yarn.lock` instead of the `package-lock.json` given your using `yarn add ...`